# SSH Update and .profile is not sourced anymore

Tags: ssh

On a RHEL5 System with `openssh-5.3p1-84.1.el6.x86_64` I defined the variable `BLA` in `~/.profile`:

```
export BLA=hello
```

Then I run the following:

```
# ssh localhost 'echo $BLA'
# hello
```

I see that the variable `BLA` is defined.

When I compile `openssh-6.2p2` from source and I use the same ssh configuration files, the variable is not defined anymore:

```
 # ssh localhost 'echo $BLA'
 #
```

Any suggestions what I am missing?

BR, Rene

Answer (score 1):

From the *AcceptEnv* section in the *sshd_config* man page:

"... The default is not to accept any environment variables."

Red Hat may not have used the default in their package, but your version compiled from source may have used the default setting as listed in the man page.